"Mal e porcamente" ou "mal e parcamente"?
Eu sempre ouvi "mal e porcamente" em pt-Br.  Contudo veio um amigo dizer-me que o correto seria "mal e parcamente" .
Exemplo: Ele fez o serviço mal e porcamente/parcamente.


porcamente - de modo sujo, imundo (porco, Priberam)
parcamente - ter comedimento nas despesas ou no que se consome, evitar os excessos, ser frugal ou sóbrio. (Dicionário Online)


Até que "mal e parcamente" parece aceitável em determinados contextos. Mas o significado é certamente diferente de "mal e porcamente".

Também sempre ouvi só "mal e porcamente".

https://www.recantodasletras.com.br/gramatica/2845028 mal e porcamente é um deterioro da expressão mal e parcamente. Só que agora existem os dois, né? Ele comia mal e porcamente. c. Ele comia mal e parcamente

Se quiser, posso colocar meu comentário como resposta...

@Lambie  Fique à vontade.

Infelizmente, não é possível reproduzir, até citando o nome do autor. Teria de redigitar o trecho inteiro. Que pena. –

Creio que "mal e parcamente" é um eufemismo, evitando a referência a porcos. Mas as expressões não são realmente sinônimas; "mal e parcamente" significa "mal e pouco", "mal e porcamente" significa "mal e de forma grosseira". Talvez funcionem da mesma forma no caso de um verbo como "trabalhar", mas no caso de comer o significado é bem diferente, até tendendo à antonímia.

A expressão «mal e parcamente» apareceu-me 2 vezes numa pesquisa no século XIX e curiosamente, os resultados são do Brasil e parecem ser do mesmo autor. Não sei se é só coincidência ou não, o que é certo é que a primeira ocorrência é em 1887.
Enquanto que, a expressão «mal e porcamente» apareceu-me 29 vezes numa pesquisa no século XIX e a primeira ocorrência é em 1858 no «Diccionario da lingua Portugueza» como se pode ver na imagem:

Talvez tenham tentado embelezar a expressão «mal e porcamente»... O que é certo é que neste contexto do dicionário a expressão é usada com o significado atual.
Fazendo uma pesquisa mais atual, século XX, encontramos algumas referências, 35, a citar a «mal e parcamente» sobretudo no Brasil. Enquanto que encontramos 463 referências de «mal e porcamente».
Faz parecer que não será um deterioro, mas talvez um embelezamento.

Entretanto encontrei uma resposta no Quora e tem outra referência mais antiga, num texto publicado em 1815, por Jerónimo José Nogueira de Andrade, na revista O Investigador Português em Inglaterra:

A autora dessa resposta também acha que a expressão começou como «mal e porcamente» e o mais curioso é que também lhe parece que os resultados para «mal e parcamente» são na sua maioria a corrigir «mal e porcamente». Eu também tinha ficado com essa ideia...

Quanto mais pesquiso mais fico com a ideia que tudo começou com «mal e porcamente», agora encontrei uma derivação da expressão num livro de 1748, O desejoso ou, Espelho de monges e pessoas religiosas; obra espiritual:


Mais um senhor que concorda que deve ter começado como «mal e porcamente»

A expressão "mal e porcamente" aparece escrita em textos mais antigos e com muito mais ocorrências que "mal e parcamente". (tanto em pt-pt como em pt-br).
Na minha opinião (que vale o que vale) não se trata dum deterioro, mas de um mito urbano.
